# Network share slow down over time

Tags: mac-osx-server, file-sharing, network-speed

We have a Mac mini 2018 which share the content of a Raid NAS and after like 6-7 days the read/write speed of the connected user drop down, what would be a good way to investigate what is the problem ?

Here's some details about the setup :

- Mac mini server, using built-in sharing services
- 6 mac and 2 pc are connected to it (mac are connected via AFP)
- Everything pass throught a WTR1900AC router, generic configurations, nothing special there
- The write/read speed is 90/105 MB/s normally, but drop as low as 3/5 MB/s
- As soon as we restart the router and server everything come back
- When I check the "statistics" tab in macOS Server, everything is fine, processor run at 15%, RAM at 6go/16go, memory load at 20%, and network trafic vary between 1MB/s to 40MB/s, with an average at 5MB/s

Answer (score 1):

Put a switch and do a test, don't forget the router is already using it's CPU/Memory cycle for the WAN/Wifi, and even if all port are tagged 1000mbps, not all router support a full 1000mpbs per ports.

And as you state it,

> As soon as we restart the router and server everything come back

It point to your router that act as a switch.

Comment: What do you mean by "your router act as a switch" ? If I'm correct, the difference between router and switch is that router manage what goes where, vs the switch send to everyone and the destination is responsible for "accepting" the data right ? How could a router stop...routing the data ?

Also, if we find that the router is the problem, would you recommend a specific model for a replacement, we though about going to 10gbps (the server already has a 10gbsp port), would that help, even if not every computer has a 10gbps port + cat 7 cable ?